# Peer Pressure Badge

Tags: discussion

I have to admit that I find it to be very humiliating to be the recipient of a peer pressure badge and I have lost some respect for myself over it. Is there anyone else who feels this badge should be renamed at the very least.

Comment: Really a q for meta.SE -- should I migrate?

Comment: It will probably be closed there as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107628/205264, although the point here is slightly different.

Comment: If your answer was simply wrong as pointed out by commenters but you honestly thought it was correct when you typed it, I see no shame whatsoever in removing your answer. Don't be discouraged by that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to feel humiliated because

1. Not many users will know you have this badge unless they try to find what kind of badge you have by visiting your personal profile page and looking into it.
2. They are well hidden with other badges.

I have a few of them myself on other sites and I don't feel humiliated at all because I don't care. I just wanted to delete my poorly-received post because leaving them will humiliate me more than receiving a weirdly-named badge. (I didn't even know the badge existed before receiving the first one.)

As commented above, if you have a better idea on how to rename it or you think it should not be awarded, you should ask it on Meta SE as it will be across-SE feature change. But note that your question might be heavily downvoted unless you include a very convincing argument.

Good luck.

Comment: Its the idea of basing my happiness and self esteem by a down vote or up vote talley and essentially feeling like a child seeking approval that is the core issue. If I find any post of mine to be acceptable or even great then that is what matters. At this point becoming a complete failure on this site seems more like a win and were they alive today most of the philosophers I admire would be my company.

Answer (score 0):

A badge is a badge. If you can't have what you want, you can want what you have, and wear it proudly. I admit that I felt terrible after my first Q or A were  downvoted. But I choosed to stay around here, and try to consider downvotes as lessons learned, and earning a badge for that is a path to acceptance.

I do not mean that downvotes are always right. Different SE communities behave differently: some a very inclusive, and others are exclusive. You have to pass a test. The first reputation points are sometimes hard to earn. After a while, a downvote does not really matter: same number of points removed, but relatively unnoticeable. However, they still mean that something can be improved in you Q or A.